# curtin/autoinstall storage section fails on swap mount in config

Tags: swap, curtin

I'm using storage section of autoinstal for simple custom /dev/sda disk layout: sda1 (512MB) /boot, sda2 (2GB) swap, sda3 (-1) /. I'm having problem defining swap properly. [Curtin docs](https://gist.github.com/allenap/49252ff25768b2f72e65) claim it to be:

1. define partition,
2. define format with fstype: swap,
3. define mount *without* path with some options: (options: pri=1,discard=pages).

My simple config:

```
  storage:
    version: 1
#    swap:
#      filename: /dev/sda2
#      size: 2GB
#      maxsize: 2GB
    config:
      - type: disk
        id: sda
        path: /dev/sda
        ptable: msdos
        name: system-disk
        wipe: superblock
        grub_device: true
      - type: partition
        id: sda-sda1
        number: 1
        size: 512MB
        device: sda
        name: boot-partition
        flag: boot
      - type: partition
        id: sda-sda2
        number: 2
        size: 2GB
        device: sda
        name: swap-partition
        flag: swap
      - type: partition
        id: sda-sda3
        number: 3
        size: -1
        device: sda
        name: root-partition
      - type: format
        id: sda-sda1-fs
        fstype: ext4
        label: boot
        volume: sda-sda1
      - type: format
        id: sda-sda2-fs
        fstype: swap
        label: swap
        volume: sda-sda2
      - type: format
        id: sda-sda3-fs
        fstype: ext4
        label: root
        volume: sda-sda3
      - type: mount
        id: sda-sda1-fs-mount1
        path: /boot
        device: sda-sda1-fs
      - type: mount
        id: sda-sda2-fs-mount1
        options: pri=2,discard=pages
        device: sda-sda2-fs
      - type: mount
        id: sda-sda3-fs-mount1
        path: /
        device: sda-sda3-fs
```

At install I get is: "`TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'`". If I remove entry with id: sda-sda2-fs-mount1 (the one for swap) and uncomment swap section pointing to /dev/sda2. I get working swap.
How to define swap using only config section. Mixing several solutions is not elegant solution imho.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try adding the argument `path: none` and seeing if that works.  Looking at the source for *curtin*, that appears to be what it does when there is no path value and the file system is 'swap'

https://github.com/canonical/curtin/blob/b4f5078663d9cbfd31a7d23b77c458e6a7447226/curtin/commands/block_meta.py#L1107

I have not setup swap like this, but your link is to some guy's four year old gist snippet.  The *curtin* docs are at
https://curtin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/storage.html?#mount-command

Quotes from the mount section

> The path to the target mountpoint must be specified as well as the target filesystem

> If the device specified is formatted as swap space, then an entry will be added to the target system’s /etc/fstab to make use of this swap space.

I have found the *curtin* docs to be wrong before, so I found this file that appears to define the schema requirements.  I'm not certain how to parse it, but it would seem to me that `path` is not required since you have a `device` argument

https://github.com/canonical/curtin/blob/master/curtin/block/schemas.py

There is also the possibility *subiquity* is what is generating the error.  *subiquity* does its own yaml validation.  It uses this schema, but it looks like the `storage` section has no requirements.  I'm guessing they rely on *curtin* for the validation

https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-schema

Comment: path: none  for swap works for me

Comment: yup path: none works !!!